# Checking timeouts made more readable

Tags: c#, design, readability

I have several situations where I need to control timeouts in a technical application. Either in a loop or as a simple check. Of course – handling this is *really easy*, but none of these is looking cute.

To clarify, here is some C# (Pseudo) code:

```
private DateTime girlWentIntoBathroom;
girlWentIntoBathroom = DateTime.Now;

do
{
  // do something
} while (girlWentIntoBathroom.AddSeconds(10) > DateTime.Now);
```

or

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom.AddSeconds(10) > DateTime.Now)
  MessageBox.Show("Wait a little longer");
else
  MessageBox.Show("Knock louder");
```

Now I was inspired by something a saw in Ruby [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10192257/582483):

Now I’m wondering if this construct can be made more readable using extension methods. My goal is something that can be read like

> “If girlWentIntoBathroom is more than 10 seconds ago”

**1st attempt**

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom > (10).Seconds().Ago())
  MessageBox.Show("Wait a little longer");
else
  MessageBox.Show("Knock louder");
```

So I wrote an extension for integer that converts the integer into a TimeSpan

```
public static TimeSpan Seconds(this int amount)
{
  return new TimeSpan(0, 0, amount);
}
```

After that, I wrote an extension for TimeSpan like this:

```
public static DateTime Ago(this TimeSpan diff)
{
  return DateTime.Now.Add(-diff);
}
```

This works fine so far, but has a great disadvantage. **The logic is inverted!** Since girlWentIntoBathroom is a timestamp in the past, the right side of the equation needs to count backwards: impossible.
Just inverting the equation is no solution, because it will invert the read sentence as well.

**2nd attempt**
So I tried something new:

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom.IsMoreThan(10).SecondsAgo())
  MessageBox.Show("Knock louder");
else
  MessageBox.Show("Wait a little longer");
```

IsMoreThan() needs to transport the past timestamp as well as the span for the extension SecondsAgo(). It could be:

```
public static DateWithIntegerSpan IsMoreThan(this DateTime baseTime, int span)
{
  return new DateWithIntegerSpan() { Date = baseTime, Span = span };
}
```

Where DateWithIntegerSpan is simply:

```
public class DateWithIntegerSpan
{
  public DateTime Date {get; set;}
  public int Span { get; set; }
}
```

And SecondsAgo() is

```
public static bool SecondsAgo(this DateWithIntegerSpan dateAndSpan)
{
  return dateAndSpan.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, dateAndSpan.Span)) < DateTime.Now;
}
```

Using this approach, the English sentence matches the expected behavior. But the disadvantage is, that I need a helping class (DateWithIntegerSpan).

Has anyone an idea to make checking timeouts look more cute and closer to a readable sentence? Am I a little too insane thinking about something minor like this?

Comment: Why is your helper class a problem? You'll find most "fluent" interfaces (which is what you're building here) involve a command builder class which implements several syntax interfaces.

Comment: I think that trying to write code as actual English sentences won't work well, no matter what you try.

Comment: @pdr: I'm not familiar with "fluent" interfaces. It just "feels" superfluous creating a class just for this single usage

Comment: It seems superfluous to change the syntax of the language/framework, to make it read like English (Ruby is an entire language designed based on a desire to do that, so of course its metaprogramming ability is more easily flexed). But that doesn't mean you shouldn't. :)

Comment: @pdr: So you recommend to handle it "old style" because everything else is possible but more like violating the language?

Comment: I'm saying that there's very little reason not to do it old-style. No C# developer is going to find it hard-to-read. However, if you feel the desire to do it anyway, as a thought-exercise, then you should. But superfluous classes often come with superfluous work. See what I mean? ie. Your second solution is just fine, although I might make Ago() a member of DateWithIntegerSpan and give it a name like DateComparisonBuilder.

Comment: @pdr: Ok I see. If you post this as answer, I'm going to accept this (tomorrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve a none existent problem. Programming is not about writing proper english sentences (and I'm not a native english speaker, so pardon the english).

I find this code hard to read:

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom.IsMoreThan(10).SecondsAgo())
```

I have no idea that `girlWentIntoBathroom` contains a date/time. I have to read the method `SecondsAgo` to udnerstand that, and then go back to the beginning of the line and re-read everything to understand what it does.

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom > 10.Seconds().Ago())
```

Is more readable, I can by looking at `10.Seconds()` tell that `girlWentIntoBathroom` is some kind of date/time unit.

While this is enough for me:

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).Ago())
```

Since I'm used to the `TimeSpan` structure.

This is just fine too:

```
if (girlWentIntoBathroom > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-10))
```

Since we are after all programmers and `AddSeconds(-10)` will therefore make sense.

Comment: Your first example should read `if(girlWentIntoBathroom.MoreThan(10).SecondsAgo())`  Fluent interfaces are not about understanding the underlying code; it's the difference between Linq sugar (which is more English-like), and Linq Extension methods (which are more programmatic).  But, like you, I dislike this kind of obfuscation.